# How can i play pause swiper js autoplay instead of start stop which restarts the timer?

Tags: swiper.js

is there any workaround wherein on mouse hover it pauses and on leaving it resumes not restarts. I tried pauseOnMouseEnter, but it restarted the autoplay instead of resuming.

```
const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
  modules: [Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay],
  slidesPerView: 1,
  effect: 'fade',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 3000,
    pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
    // disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'bullets',
    clickable: 'true',
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
      return '<span class="' + className + '">' + '<em>'+'</em>' + '<i></i>' + '<b></b>'  + '</span>';
    }
  },
  
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
  }
});
```

Comment: Any ideas? The same problem here

Comment: didnt find anywhere? you have any idea?